# certain images only are appearing with a white background behind them, even though the images are transparent

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

For some reason my enemy ship and enemy bullet are appearing with a white background even though they are transparent.

Mains cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Example_Space_Game
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Random random = new Random();
        public int enemyBulletDamage;

        //List
        List<Asteroid> asteroidList = new List<Asteroid>();
        List<Enemy> enemyList = new List<Enemy>();

        //Instantiating new player and objects
        Player p = new Player();
        Starfield sf = new Starfield();       

        //constructor
        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 950;
            this.Window.Title = " XNA - 2D Space Shooter ";
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            enemyBulletDamage = 10;
        }

        //init
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
        }

        //Load Content
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            p.LoadContent(Content);
            sf.LoadContent(Content);
        }

        //Unload Content
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
        }

        //Update
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            //Updating enemy's and checking collision of enemyship to playership
            foreach (Enemy e in enemyList)
            {
                //check if enemyship is colliding with player
                if(e.boundingBox.Intersects(p.boundingBox))
                {
                    p.health -= 40;
                    e.isVisible = false;
                }

                //check enemy bullet collision with player ship
                for(int i = 0; i < e.bulletList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(p.boundingBox.Intersects(e.bulletList[i].boundingBox))
                    {
                        p.health -= enemyBulletDamage;
                        e.bulletList[i].isVisible = false;
                    }
                }

                //check player bullet collision to enemy ship
                for (int i = 0; i < p.bulletlist.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(p.bulletlist[i].boundingBox.Intersects(e.boundingBox))
                    {
                        p.bulletlist[i].isVisible = false;
                        e.isVisible = false;
                    }
                }

                e.Update(gameTime);
            }


            //for each asteroid in our asteroidList, update it and check for collisions
            foreach(Asteroid a in asteroidList)
            {
                //check to see if any of the asteroids are colliding with our playership, if they are... set invisible to false (remove then from our list)
                if(a.boundingBox.Intersects(p.boundingBox))
                {
                    p.health -= 20;
                    a.isVisible = false;
                }

                //iterate through our bulletList if any asteroid come in contacts with these bullets, destroyed bullet and asteroid
                for (int i = 0; i < p.bulletlist.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(a.boundingBox.Intersects(p.bulletlist[i].boundingBox))
                    {
                        a.isVisible = false;
                        p.bulletlist.ElementAt(i).isVisible = false;
                    }
                }

                a.Update(gameTime);
            }

            p.Update(gameTime);
            sf.Update(gameTime);
            LoadAsteroids();
            LoadEnemies();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        //Draw Content
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            spriteBatch.Begin();

            sf.Draw(spriteBatch);
            p.Draw(spriteBatch);
            foreach(Asteroid a in asteroidList)
            {
                a.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }

            foreach(Enemy e in enemyList)
            {
                e.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }

            spriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        //Load Asteroids
        public void LoadAsteroids()
        {
            // Creating random variables for our x and y axis of our controls
            int randY = random.Next(-600, -50);
            int randX = random.Next(0, 750);

            //if there are less than 5 asteroids on the screen, than create more until there is 5 again
            if(asteroidList.Count() < 5)
            {
                asteroidList.Add(new Asteroid(Content.Load<Texture2D>("asteroid"), new Vector2(randX, randY)));
            }

            //if any of the enemies in the list were destroyed (or invisible), then remove from the list
            for (int i = 0; i < asteroidList.Count; i++)
            {
                if(!asteroidList[i].isVisible)
                {
                    asteroidList.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }

        //Load Enemies
        public void LoadEnemies()
        {
            // Creating random variables for our x and y axis of our controls
            int randY = random.Next(-600, -50);
            int randX = random.Next(0, 750);

            //if there are less than 3 enemies on the screen, than create more until there is 3 again
            if(enemyList.Count() < 3)
            {
                enemyList.Add(new Enemy(Content.Load<Texture2D>("enemyship"), new Vector2(randX, randY), Content.Load<Texture2D>("EnemyBullet")));
            }

            //if any of the enemies in the list were destroyed (or invisible), then remove from the list
            for (int i = 0; i < enemyList.Count; i++)
            {
                if(!enemyList[i].isVisible)
                {
                    enemyList.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Enemy cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

    namespace Example_Space_Game
    {
        public class Enemy
        {
            public Rectangle boundingBox;
            public Texture2D texture, bulletTexture;
            public Vector2 position;
            public int health, speed, bulletDelay, currentDifficultyLevel;
            public bool isVisible;
            public List<Bullet> bulletList;

            //Constructor
            public Enemy(Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition, Texture2D newBulletTexture)
            {
                bulletList = new List<Bullet>();
                texture = newTexture;
                bulletTexture = newBulletTexture;
                health = 5;
                position = newPosition;
                currentDifficultyLevel = 1;
                bulletDelay = 40;
                speed = 5;
                isVisible = true;
            }

            //Update
            public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
            {
                //Update Collision rectangle
                boundingBox = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height);

                //Update enemy movement
                position.Y += speed;

                //Move enemy to top of the screen if he fly's off the bottom
                if (position.Y >= 950)
                    position.Y = -75;

                EnemyShoot();
                UpdateBullets();
            }

            //Draw
            public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
            {
                //Draw enemy ship
                spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);

                //Drwa enemy bullets
                foreach (Bullet b in bulletList)
                {
                    b.Draw(spriteBatch);
                }
            }

            //Update bullet function
            public void UpdateBullets()
            {
                //for each bullet in out bulletList: update the movement and if the bullet hits the top of the screen remove it from the list
               foreach (Bullet b in bulletList)
               {
                   //BoundingBox for every bullet in our bulletList
                   b.boundingBox = new Rectangle((int)b.position.X, (int)b.position.Y, b.texture.Width, b.texture.Height);

                   //set movement for bullet
                   b.position.Y = b.position.Y + b.speed;

                   //if bullet hits the top of the screen, then make visible false
                   if (b.position.Y >= 950)
                       b.isVisible = false;
               }

                //iterate through bulletList and see if any of the bullets are not visible, if they aren't then remove that bullet from out bullet list
                for (int i = 0; i < bulletList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(!bulletList[i].isVisible)
                    {
                        bulletList.RemoveAt(i);
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            }

            //enemy shoot function
            public void EnemyShoot()
            {
                //Shoot only if the bulletdelay resets
                if (bulletDelay >= 0)
                    bulletDelay--;

                if(bulletDelay <= 0)
                {
                    //create new bullet and position it front and centre of enemy ship
                    Bullet newBullet = new Bullet(bulletTexture);
                    newBullet.position = new Vector2(position.X + texture.Width / 2 - newBullet.texture.Width / 2, position.Y + 30);

                    newBullet.isVisible = true;

                    if (bulletList.Count() < 20)
                        bulletList.Add(newBullet);
                }

                //reset bullet delay
                if (bulletDelay == 0)
                    bulletDelay = 40;
            }
        }
    }
```

Bullet cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Example_Space_Game
{
    //Main
    public class Bullet
    {
        public Rectangle boundingBox;
        public Texture2D texture;
        public Vector2 origin;
        public Vector2 position;
        public bool isVisible;
        public float speed;

        //Constructor
        public Bullet(Texture2D newTexture)
        {
            speed = 10;
            texture = newTexture;
            isVisible = false;

        }

        //Draw
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

player cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;


namespace Example_Space_Game
{
    //main
    public class Player
    {
        public Texture2D texture, bulletTexture, healthTexture;
        public Vector2 position, healthbarPosition;
        public int speed, health;
        public float bulletDelay;
        public Rectangle boundingBox, healthRectangle;
        public bool IsColliding;
        public List<Bullet> bulletlist;

        //---Contructor---
        public Player()
        {
            bulletlist = new List<Bullet>();
            texture = null;
            position = new Vector2(300, 300);
            bulletDelay = 1;
            speed = 10;
            IsColliding = false;
            health = 200;
            healthbarPosition = new Vector2(50, 50);
        }

        //---Load Content---
        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship");
            bulletTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("playerbullet");
            healthTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("healthbar");
        }

        //---Draw---
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(healthTexture, healthRectangle, Color.White);

            foreach (Bullet b in bulletlist)
                b.Draw(spriteBatch);



        }

        //---Update---
        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            //Getting Keyboard State
            KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();

            //BoundingBox for player ship
            boundingBox = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height);

            //Set rectangle for health bar
            healthRectangle = new Rectangle((int)healthbarPosition.X,(int)healthbarPosition.Y, health, 25);

            //Fire bullets
            if(keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
            {
                Shoot();
            }

            UpdateBullets();
            //Ship Controls
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
                position.Y = position.Y - speed;

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                position.X = position.X - speed;

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                position.Y = position.Y + speed;

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                position.X = position.X + speed;

            //keep ship in scren bounds
            if (position.X <= 0)
                position.X = 0;

            if (position.X >= 800 - texture.Width)
                position.X = 800 - texture.Width;

            if (position.Y <= 0)
                position.Y = 0;

            if (position.Y >= 950 - texture.Height)
                position.Y = 950 - texture.Height;
        }

        //---Shoot Method: used to set starting position of our bullets---
        public void Shoot()
        {
            //shoot only if bullet delay resets
            if (bulletDelay >= 0)
                bulletDelay--;

            //if bullet delay is at 0: create a new bullet at player position, make it visible, then add the bulel to the list
            if (bulletDelay <= 0)
            {
                Bullet newBullet = new Bullet(bulletTexture);
                newBullet.position = new Vector2(position.X + 32 - newBullet.texture.Width / 2, position.Y + 30);

                //Making bullet visible
                newBullet.isVisible = true;

                if (bulletlist.Count() < 20)
                    bulletlist.Add(newBullet);
            }

            //reset bullet delay
            if (bulletDelay == 0)
                bulletDelay = 20;
        }

        //---Update bullet function---
        public void UpdateBullets()
        {
            //for each bullet in out bulletlist: update the movement and if the bullet hits the top of the screen remove it from the list
            foreach (Bullet b in bulletlist)
            {
                //boundbox for our every bullet in our bulletlist
                b.boundingBox = new Rectangle((int)b.position.X, (int)b.position.Y, b.texture.Width, b.texture.Height);

                //set movement for bullet
                b.position.Y = b.position.Y - b.speed;

                //if bullet hits the top of the screen, then make visible false
                if(b.position.Y<=0)
                    b.isVisible=false;
            }

            //Iterate through the bulletlist and see if any of the bullets are not visible, if they aren't remove that bullet from our bulletlist
            for (int i = 0; i < bulletlist.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!bulletlist[i].isVisible)
                {
                    bulletlist.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Asteroid cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;


namespace Example_Space_Game
{
   public class Asteroid
    {
       public Rectangle boundingBox;
       public Texture2D texture;
       public Vector2 position;
       public Vector2 origin;
       public float rotationAngle;
       public int speed;

       public bool isVisible;
       Random random = new Random();
       public float randX, randY;

       //Constructor
       public Asteroid(Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition)
       {
           position = newPosition;
           texture = newTexture;
           speed = 4;
           isVisible = true;
           randX = random.Next(0, 750);
           randY = random.Next(-600, -50);

       }

       //Load Content
       public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
       {

       }

       //Update
       public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
       {
           //Set bounding box for collision
           boundingBox=new Rectangle((int)position.X,(int)position.Y, 45, 45);

           //updating origin for rotation
           //origin.X = texture.Width / 2;
           //origin.Y = texture.Height / 2;

           //Udate Movement
           position.Y = position.Y + speed;
           if (position.Y>=950)
               position.Y=-50;

           //Rotate Asteroid
           //float elapsed =(float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
           //rotationAngle += elapsed;
           //float circle=MathHelper.Pi * 2;
           //rotationAngle=rotationAngle % circle;
       }

       //Draw
       public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
       {
           if(isVisible)
               spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
       }
    }
}
```

starfield cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
namespace Example_Space_Game
{
    public class Starfield
    {
        public Texture2D texture;
        public Vector2 bgPos1, bgPos2;
        public int speed;

        //Constructor
        public Starfield()
        {
            texture=null;
            bgPos1=new Vector2(0,0);
            bgPos2 = new Vector2(0, -950);
            speed=5;

        }

        //Load Content
        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("space");
        }

        //Draw
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, bgPos1, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, bgPos2, Color.White);
        }

        //Update
        public void Update(GameTime gametime)
        {
            //Setting speed for background scrolling
            bgPos1.Y = bgPos1.Y + speed;
            bgPos2.Y = bgPos2.Y + speed;

            //Scrolling background (repeating)
            if (bgPos1.Y >=950)
            {
                bgPos1.Y = 0;
                bgPos2.Y = -950;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Above are all my code, not quite sure how to screenshot my game been played so you can see whats going on as well. But for some reason its just my enemy bullet and ship which are showing with a white background. I've checked them in photoshop they are transparent as are all of the rest of the images.

If anyone could be of any help would be very great ful thank you

Comment: all the images are .png,

Comment: I guess you need to set BlendMode for the graphics device / sprite batch, to use AlphaBlend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
```

Try using

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
```

AlphaBlend is "A built-in state object with settings for alpha blend that is blending the source and destination data using alpha."